# Java: What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the sum of each individual number in a number but it is not giving the correct answer. What is wrong with my code?

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Tallist {
       public static void main(String[]args) {               
          int sum = 0;   
             String tal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "skriv ett tal");   
                for(int X = 0; X<=15; X++) {                               
                   sum += tal.charAt(X);     
                      System.out.println(sum);  




      }            
   }
}
```

Comment: " i keep getting this error"  and what is the error ?

Comment: Your code is riddled with (logical and other). What is the error you get? What symbol can't be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** of all, if you want to iterate through the entire string, you should not fix the number of iterations to 15 in your for-loop.

```
for(int X = 0; X<=15; X++)
```

Could be written as:

```
for(int x=0; x<tal.length(); x++)   //user lower case for non-final variables
```

**Next**, you are summing up the **ASCII** value of the input string, not the numbers.
So if `"123"` was input into the InputDialog, you are summing up **ASCII for 123**: `(49 + 50 + 51)` instead of adding up `(1+2+3)`.

Just convert it to integers before summing up:

```
sum += Character.getNumericValue(tal.charAt(x));
```

Comment: @samueltober If that solves your problem, you can click the `tick` beside my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to calculate the crossfoot of a number.

Here the code you need with user input via input dialog:

```
public class Crossfoot
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number:");

        if (!isInteger(userInput))
        {
            continue;
        }

        int crossfoot = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
        {
            crossfoot += Character.getNumericValue(userInput.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println(crossfoot);
    }
}

public static boolean isInteger(String string)
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(string);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

As another user already wrote, you should iterate over the whole string and be careful with the ASCII values of the characters.